# Rspec validation failed: Photo can't be blank

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to create a test for a model which has a photo as a mandatory association.
This is my model:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :photo

  validates :name, uniqueness: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :photo, presence: true
end
```

and this is my test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Car', type: :model do
  let(:valid_attributes) do
    {
      name: 'Audi'
    }
  end

  it 'name is unique' do
    Car.create!(name: 'Audi')
    car = Car.new(name: 'Audi')
    expect(car).not_to be_valid
  end
end
```

The result of the test is:

```
Failures:

  1) Car name is unique
     Failure/Error: Car.create!(name: 'Audi')
     
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Photo can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/car_model_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

What I can't do is attach a photo for testing. Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have guessed, to pass the validation, you have to add a picture to your test :)

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Car', type: :model do
  let(:valid_attributes) do
    {
      name: 'Audi'
    }
  end

  let(:photo) do
    Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(
      Rails.root.join('path/to/image.png'), 'image/png'
    )
  end

  it 'name is unique' do
    Car.create!(name: 'Audi', photo: photo)

    car = Car.new(name: 'Audi', photo: photo)
    expect(car).not_to be_valid
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Car` model, you have the following:

```
validates :photo, presence: true
```

Which means every `Car` must have a `photo`. When you write this in your specs:

```
Car.create!(name: 'Audi')
```

You are trying to create a car without a photo. Hence the error saying the validation failed as the photo cannot be blank.
You can either remove `validates :photo, presence: true`, or pass in `photo: some_photo_url` to the `Car.create!()`:

```
Car.create!(name: 'Audi', photo: some_photo_url)
```

Where `some_photo_url` is the url of a photo of the car.
For saving images to records in ActiveRecord, you should look into `Active::Storage` https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html

Comment: Typo: ActiveStorage*

Comment: I tried adding the a url of a photo while creating the instance but it does not work. I also tried with 
`first_car = car.new(name: 'Audi')

first_car.photo.attach(io: File.open('/app/assets/images/'), filename: 'audi.jpeg', content_type: 'image/jpg')`
but I got  No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen